# How to convert ASP.NET code to HTML at run time?

Tags: asp.net, html

How do I convert [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) code to HTML at runtime?

Like it is done in the Visual Studio IDE (Source to Design). When I entered some code like below to a text box and click a button

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

it should convert it to HTML and render the button.

Comment: That's default behaviour? Not sure what you're asking..

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to compile the source?

You may want to check out Visual Studio Express edition (free) or alternatively look at compiling through command line:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293881.aspx

Comment: i want to compile the asp.net code at runtime, and show the button

Comment: YOu may want to check out Microsoft Visual Studio Express, it is a free IDE that lets you do that:

http://www.microsoft.com/express

Comment: Sorry, i need to handle it pragmatically using a ASP.NET web site like this Try it yourself editor in w3schools

Comment: Your question doesn't really make any sense, could you rephrase it?

Comment: @ChaturaDilanPerera please provide a link to what you are referring to at W3Schools